# Groovy Script for PhpStorm Live Templates give suggested box?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

So I have a little silly problem. I have a groovy script that reads all files in a folder and then manipulates the files in such a way to output the file names for the user to select the correct one in the live template variable. My problem is that the auto suggestion list only displays 1 item and not multiple items to select from in the IDE.

Here is the live template setup:

[image]

This is the output:

[image]

This is what I want (without using `enum()`):

[image]

This is the piece of code:

```
groovyScript("import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES;def curPath = _editor.getVirtualFile().getPath().split('/src/')[0];def dir = new File(curPath+'/src/partials');def files = [];dir.traverse(type: FILES, maxDepth: 1) { files.add(it.toString().replace('/src/partials/','').replace(curPath,'').replace('.html','')) }; return files;",methodParameters())
```

Please help... Since google searches does not yield any proper answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3, the groovyScript() feature does not support generating a list of suggestions. It can only be used to calculate a single suggestion which is then inserted into the editor.

Comment: Thanks... well that sucks big time.

Comment: Where can I post a feature request to get that functionality back? :) I really need it.

Comment: Why "back"? It was never there. You can file feature requests to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: Issue can be followed here for future reference:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-44436